# Auto logger for C/C++ on window

Tags: c++, logging

I am looking for a solution that can output log automatically with minimum of log code. I need  to log the line number where is the function is entering and exiting.

For example: in file example.cpp

```
Line 1  :   void Fun1() 
Line 2  :   {   
Line 3  :       AUTO_LOG_MACRO;
Line 4  :       //do something 1
Line 5  :       //do something 2
Line 6  :       return;
Line 7  :   }   
Line 8  :       
Line 9  :   void Fun2() 
Line 10 :   {   
Line 11 :       AUTO_LOG_MACRO;
Line 12 :       //do something 1
Line 13 :       //do something 2
Line 14 :       Func1();
Line 15 :       //do something 1
Line 16 :       //do something 2
Line 17 :       return;
Line 18 :   }
```

Then the log file will be:

example.cpp, line 11, Func2 enter
example.cpp, line 03, Func1 enter
example.cpp, line 06, Func1 exit
example.cpp, line 17, Func2 exit

I don't want to add many logging code like below

```
Line 1  :   void Fun1()     
Line 2  :   {       
Line 3  :       FUNCTION_ENTER; 
Line 4  :       //do something 1    
Line 5  :       //do something 2    
Line 6  :       if (bCheckFail1)    
Line 7  :       {   
Line 8  :           FUNCTION_EXIT;
Line 9  :           return;
Line 10 :       }   
Line 11 :       //do something 3    
Line 12 :       if (bCheckFail2)    
Line 13 :       {   
Line 14 :           FUNCTION_EXIT;
Line 15 :           return;
Line 16 :       }   
Line 17 :       //do something 4    
Line 18 :       FUNCTION_EXIT;  
Line 19 :       return; 
Line 20 :   }
```

Comment: If that's all you need just write an object that logs in the ctor and the dtor.  Use `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, and `__FUNC__`

Comment: How to get the line of code at that log object is destruction?

Comment: If you are trying to get the exact line number that returns from the function that's a lot harder and I don't think there is an easy answer.  There can be multiple exit points.  I suppose you could wrap your own versions of return, exit, _exit, abort, possibly throw, etc., but this seems a little nuts to me.

Comment: To be honest I've been looking at the `#line` directive. However it only seems to accept an integer constant.

Comment: Hi remyabel, could you describe more detail?

Comment: @tund3010 I made an edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure it out. My results are probably purely coincidental and wrong. I will leave my answer up for reference unless you feel it should be deleted since it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This is not completely correct yet. Still haven't figured out how to get the right line number for the end of the function.

**Edit**:

After some digging, I managed to come close, but no cigar:

You have to hard code the line at which `#line` appears, plus one (because it starts counting after that line.)

```
class LogTemporary {
    int line;
    std::string function;
public:
    LogTemporary(int nline, std::string nfunction) : line(nline), function(nfunction) {
        #line 13
        std::cout<<nline<< " " << nfunction << " enter " << std::endl;
    }
    ~LogTemporary() {
        std::cout<<__LINE__+line-13<< " " << function << " exit " << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Here are my results:

```
30 Func2 enter 
22 Func1 enter 
25 Func1 exit 
33 Func2 exit
```

`Func2 exit` is off by 3. The rest are correct, however.

[Ideone link for reference](http://ideone.com/pQyMWC)

---

As suggested, you can use a temporary object. The object will be limited to the scope of the function call, therefore calling the destructor once it dies (at the end of the function.)

```
#include <iostream>

class LogTemporary {
    int line;
    std::string function;
public:
    LogTemporary(int nline, std::string nfunction) : line(nline), function(nfunction) {
        std::cout<<nline<< " " << nfunction << " enter " << std::endl;
    }
    ~LogTemporary() {
        std::cout<<line<< " " << function << " exit " << std::endl;
    }
};

#define AUTO_LOG_MACRO LogTemporary log_temporary(__LINE__, __FUNCTION__);

void Func1() 
{   
    AUTO_LOG_MACRO;
    //do something 1
    //do something 2
    return;
}   

void Func2() 
{   
    AUTO_LOG_MACRO;
    //do something 1
    //do something 2
    Func1();
    //do something 1
    //do something 2
    return;
}

int main() { 
    Func2();
}
```

Example output:

```
27 Func2 enter 
19 Func1 enter 
19 Func1 exit 
27 Func2 exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the line number of exit is wrong, it is enter line, not exit line.